# Undoing Move Led to Delete

Tags: windows-10, undo, move

I am hoping someone can help me understand what happened in Windows 10. I have two folders, folder A and folder B. I did a move of files using Ctnl-X, Cntl-V, from A to B. I accidentally had selected more files than I meant to, so I hit Cntl-Z to undo the move.

The progress indicator came up. I noticed it said Deleting, but that made some sense because it needed to move the files back to folder A, and then delete the copes in folder B. Also, the time was too short for me to have clicked cancel or hit escape.

At the end, the files I wanted to move are not in folder A or B. Nor are they in the Recycle Bin. I don't need to recover them, but I would like to 1) try to figure out what happened and 2) see if I can find a list of files that were lost/affected in a log file somewhere.

Comment: Best thing to do now is recover them from your backup. Move on Windows has no safety net [most people do not realise this, unfortunately]. Cancelling halfway through is *a bad idea*. File scavenger software might find the files, but the more you use the drive the less chace that will have.

Comment: Undoing a moved file or folder in windows will not show "Deleting".. see @Tetsujin comment about cancelling halfway and screwing with the drive AT ALL (like you are probably doing RIGHT NOW) if you want to see your files again.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Luckily, I know enough to stop doing anything with the drive/computer, so there is a chance I could find something, but going to the backup is the easiest solution.